# Practical example of using embedded sql files for stored procedures as a Liquibase changeset

Tags: liquibase

May I have an examples on how to use embedded sql files for stored procedures? Should using the sql embedded files in changelog with --changeset syntax.

I've tried looking in the [docs](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html) and it shows how to write the changesets but not in particular for a stored procedure and I don't see the actual source sql file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example embedded sql file with stored procedure:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS split_token;
//

CREATE FUNCTION split_token(txt text, delimiter_text VARCHAR(255), token_index INT UNSIGNED) RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
/*! Return substring by index in delimited text */
IF CHAR_LENGTH(delimiter_text) = ''
THEN return SUBSTRING(txt, token_index, 1);
ELSE return SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(txt, delimiter_text, token_index),delimiter_text,-1);
END IF;
END
//

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS split_token2;
//

CREATE FUNCTION split_token2(txt text, delimiter_text VARCHAR(255), token_index INT UNSIGNED) RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
/*! Return substring by index in delimited text */
IF CHAR_LENGTH(delimiter_text) = ''
THEN return SUBSTRING(txt, token_index, 1);
ELSE return SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(txt, delimiter_text, token_index),delimiter_text,-1);
END IF;
END
```

The rollback script would look like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS split_token;
//

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS split_token2;
```

Changelog would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-3.8.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

 <!-- <changeSet author="SteveZ" id="external-sql+rollback-script-example" context="QA" labels="Jira1000">
   <sqlFile dbms="mysql" splitStatements="true" endDelimiter="//" stripComments="true" path="objects/function/split_token.sql"/>
   <rollback>
    <sqlFile dbms="mysql" splitStatements="true" endDelimiter="//" stripComments="true" path="objects/function/split_token_rollback.sql"/>
   </rollback>
 </changeSet> -->
  ....
</databaseChangeLog>
```